# How does the Microsoft Operations Framework define the role of Architects and architecture in the SDLC

Tags: architecture, development-process

I have been trying to get some architecture documentation passed at work. I've spoken to my CIO and he has said to me that if I prove to him that if we stay within [MOF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc506049.aspx) then we can implement it. I am not an architect, I am a software developer trying to become an architect.

I downloaded the MOF documentation and did some searches for "architect" or "architecture" and really only found 3 very minor references. So I'm trying to find out more about the role of "Architecture" in MOF.

Comment: I'm not into MOF but it seems obvious that most of architects' work will be done during the `Plan Phase`. Did you have a look at [Integrating the Plan Phase with Manage Layer SMFs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc543271.aspx)? Table 6. shows _Architecture Accountability and Its Attendant Role Types_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to architecture.

Defining an architect's role is a notoriously difficult task.  Essentially, each shop has their own approach and set of expectations around the role.

MaxS pointed out the MOF's [definition of Architecture Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc543271.aspx) which is probably one of the "very minor references" you mentioned in your question.

An Architects role is to gather together and keep together all the odds and sods that are within the application and supporting systems.  Sounds like your first real task as an architect for your employer is to understand the MOF, how it applies to your application, and how the architecture artifacts that you want fit into the overall scheme.

The CIO is essentially saying "show me the value, with respect to this operations framework, that your suggested documents bring to our environment."  IMO, that's a good, measured approach.  He gave you the rules within which to justify your request and he hasn't outright rejected your request.  Now you need to demonstrate the value they bring and how it keeps you on the path you're already on.  He's looking for enhancements, not course or directional change.

So go read the MOF.  Go understand the artifacts that MOF suggests using.  Then understand how the artifacts *you* want align with the suggested artifacts from the MOF.  *Hint:* there's not all that much new under the sun so it shouldn't be too hard to show how your preferred document formats align with an MOF suggestion.  But you need to put the up-front effort in so you can have a knowledgeable conversation with the CIO.

Comment: I had a meeting with one of my managers today and he went through it with me. It definitely seems like architecture was an after thought for MOF it's almost never mentioned and when it is ... it just says that you need to have a capacity plan or something like a monitoring plan and reliability plan, but it doesn't say how you should go about doing that or how exactly architecture would be involved in the creation of those things. There's actually very little detail for how much documentation there is.

Comment: That's an equally valid conversation to have. You can pitch that as "here's where our guiding framework is lacking and this is how we can fix it."